# Calling reloadData through delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

I have a table view which conforms to custom protocol `FoodItemProtocol` and it implements its funciton:

```
func foodItemWasTaggedAsFavorite() {
    tableView?.reloadData()
    print("foodItemWasTaggedAsFavorite")
}
```

After `foodItem` is tagged as favorite, this function is called and print statement is executed, however table view is never reloaded.

I realized I don't actually need to use delegation for this, it works fine if I call to `reloadData()` in `viewDidAppear()`. But still I'd like to know why it's not working through delegation? I've even tried to call `reloadData()` on main thread like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    tableView?.reloadData()
}
```

But I got same result.

Comment: Where are you calling `foodItemWasTaggedAsFavorite`?

Comment: In a different view controller, sorry forgot to mention that.

Comment: If you are in a different view controller, why do you need to reload the table view?

Comment: As I wrote, I realized I don't need it, but I was trying that beforehand and now I'm curious why it's not working.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the delegate method from a different view controller, `tableView` will be `nil`.

To check this, modify `foodItemWasTaggedAsFavorite` to be:

```
if let tableView = tableView {
    tableView.reloadData()
    print("foodItemWasTaggedAsFavorite")
}
```

Now check if the print statement is being printed. I'm pretty sure it won't, because `tableView` is `nil`.

However, in `viewDidAppear:`, the table view has already been loaded, so it isn't `nil`.

Also, there is no reason to reload the data if the table view isn't on screen anyways.

Comment: Well I tried your modification and print statement actually is executed.

Comment: @AdamBardon How are you determining if the table view is being reloaded?

Comment: With breakpoint inside `tableView(... cellForRowAtIndexPath ... )`

Comment: How is the view controller (the one that is calling the delegate method) being presented (modal, push, etc.)?

Comment: Show(e.g Push) embedded in nav controller which is embedded in tab bar controller, delegate view controller is within that tab bar controller as second tab bar item.

Comment: Does the presented view controller have a table view?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103770/discussion-between-troyt-and-adam-bardon).